# Using a defined value in a filter function concerning a DataFrame in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I tried to find a similar issue but didn't find anything related.. I'm new to Spark and Scala and I'm having trouble with a specific case.

I have a DataFrame as the following :

```
+---+---+------------+
|src|dst|relationship|
+---+---+------------+
|  0|238|        41.0|
|  0|159|        46.0|
|238| 12|        36.0|
|  1|235|        44.0|
|  2|139|        50.0|
+---+---+------------+
```

My problem is :
(1) I want get the destination with the lowest value of "relationship" for the src = 0 and (2) reuse this value. I'm able to get something for (1) using both `val j = orderedSrc.filter("src == 1").orderBy("relationship").select("dst").take(5)` and `val h = j(0)(0)`.

In my example it would return `j: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([238], [159])` and `h: Any = 238`.

My question is concerning (2):

How can use this `h` value inside the previous query? Something that would look like `val j = orderedSrc.filter("src==h").orderBy("relationship").select("dst").take(5)` which would return  `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([12])` ?

By advance thanks if you can help :-)!

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: `orderedSrc.filter($"relationship" === h).select($"dst")`

Comment: Perfect thank you for giving me the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use `take` in the intermediate steps (this wont scale), use a join instead:

```
val df = Seq(
  (0,238,41.0),
  (0,159, 46.0),
  (238,12,36.0),
  (1, 235, 44.0),
  (2,139,50.0)
).toDF("src","dest","relationship")


val h = df.where($"src"===0)
  .select(min(struct($"relationship",$"dest")).as("min"))

df
  .join(h,df("src")===h("min.dest"),"leftsemi")
  .show()

+---+----+------------+
|src|dest|relationship|
+---+----+------------+
|238|  12|        36.0|
+---+----+------------+
```

Or the same with Window-functions:

```
df
  .withColumn("selector",min(when($"src"===0,struct($"relationship",$"dest"))).over(Window.partitionBy()))
  .where($"src"===$"selector.dest")
  .drop($"selector")
  .show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Lamanus wrote, the solution was :

`orderedSrc.filter($"src" === h).orderBy("relationship").select($"dst").take(5)`

Many thanks!